# What is a adjective that can describe a person who thrives on and seeks negative emotions?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in *Great Expectations* by Charles Dickens, Miss Havisham is actually proud of having a "broken" heart.

Example:

> She was very ____; she placed objects around her house reminding her
>   of her recent breakup.

Comment: If you were looking for a noun, I would suggest that "martyr" might be close, and "glutton for punishment" might be better (but, obviously, is not a single word).

Answer (score -3):

"Masochistic" seems like a good fit here.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. I suggest you [edit] your answer - for example, adding a published definition (linked to the source) and perhaps a sample sentence. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)